# Global variable doesn't keep value after being changed in node

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, scope

My issue is that my code is assigning champName to a different value inside function in the readfile call. However, after the call is over, champName does not retain that value even though it is declared globally for that function. How do I fix this?

The code below is what I have right now. Previously I tried to have the for loop outside of the function, but then I would get errors about `cannot read property 'length' of undefined` even though undefined should be champsJson, which was previously defined, meaning that champsJson doesn't get updated outside of that method.

```
//This function takes in a champId (number) and returns the appropriate 
//string that is associated with that champId
function decipherChamp(champId) {
    //Local variables
    var champName = 'This should never print';
    var champsJson = ''

    //Reads champions.json into rawData
    fs.readFile('./commands/lol/champions.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if (err)
            throw err;
        champsJson = JSON.parse(data);
        for (let i = 0; i < champsJson.length; i++) {
            if (champsJson[i].championId == champId) {
                champName = champsJson[i].championName;
                console.log("champName inside fn: " + champName)
            }
        }
    });
    console.log("champName before return: " + champName)
    return champName
}
```

I've added `console.log("champName before return: " + champName)` to see what champName is right before printing, and it prints `This should never print`, the initialized value, instead of the expected result, `<The Champion's Name>`

Observed output:

`Running command lol:currgame.
champName before return: This should never print
champName inside fn: Brand
champName before return: This should never print
champName inside fn: Graves
champName before return: This should never print
champName inside fn: Tristana
champName before return: This should never print
champName inside fn: Jax
champName before return: This should never print
champName inside fn: Malzahar
champName before return: This should never print
champName inside fn: Thresh
champName before return: This should never print
champName inside fn: Galio
champName before return: This should never print
champName inside fn: Kai'Sa
champName before return: This should never print
champName inside fn: Trundle
champName before return: This should never print
champName inside fn: Kennen`

Expected output:

`Running command lol:currgame.
champName before return: Brand
champName inside fn: Brand
champName before return: Graves
champName inside fn: Graves
champName before return: Tristana
...`

I also noticed that it prints the champName before the return before the inside of the function result, which makes me believe that it is an error with my understanding of async in node, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises)

Comment: You should only `await` Promises. `.readFile` does not return a `Promise`.

Comment: I took away the await but the observed output is still the same

Comment: Read the linked question.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I read the linked question but I still don't understand. I'm just not sure why the line `champName = champsJson[i].championName;` isn't assigning champName to champsJson[i].championName anywhere outside of that function, which is why the last print isn't showing the champion name.

Comment: Because `fs.readFile` is asynchronous.

Comment: Okay, I think that actually did help. Thank you, will update with an answer when I completely fix it but that did bring me on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `fs.readFileSync()` is valid, but not necessarily a good solution.

Sync operations in Node (such as file I/O) can be [blocking](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/blocking-vs-non-blocking/) and affect your app in unexpected ways.  A better solution would be to use

```
const { promisify } = require('util');
const asyncReadFile = promisify(fs.readFile);
```

at the top of your file and change `decipherChamp()` code to something along these lines:

```
async function decipherChamp ( champId )

    let champName = `Never see me...`;
    let champData;

    try {
        const file = await asyncReadFile(...);
        champData = JSON.parse(file);
    }
    catch (e) { 
        console.error(e); // error handling - failed to read file
        champName = `FAILED!`; // or whatever when error occurs
    }

    const champ = champData.find(champ => champ.championId == champId);
    if ( champ ) {
        champName = champ.champName;
    }
    console.log(...);
    return champName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change the method call from fs.readFile to fs.readFileSync.

`champsJson = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./commands/lol/champions.json', 'utf8'))`

and to move the for loop after that assignment.